# SSIS Server Maintenance Job ends up using all of server memory

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, ssis

For some reason the SSIS Server Maintenance Job ends up having the SQL Server instance use all available server memory after a few runs (it runs every midnight). When that happens, my SSIS packages no longer have memory to run in and start swapping on disk which leads to unacceptable execution times or at worst a total hang.

So far I've been resetting the SQL Server service through Configuration Manager every morning, but that's not a viable long term solution. I have not set maximum memory limit for the SQL Server instance. Would that help? If not, what can I do?

Server information: Azure VM, 32 GB ram, no other purpose for the server than running SSIS.

Comment: The default Maximum Server Memory setting is 2,147,483,647 megabytes (2 PB) so you should probably set it to a lesser value. Have a read through [Server memory configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options). You'll need to profile your server to figure out how much memory the operating system and other applications require and choose a value slightly less than that.

Comment: "I have not set maximum memory limit for the SQL Server instance. Would that help?" That should always be set. A simple rule of thumb is to leave 4GB or 10% of total memory free, whichever is larger.

Comment: I added information about the server and also set SQL Server maximum memory usage to 28 gigabytes. Let's see what that does.

Comment: since you are on a VM, you also need to set a memory reservation at the host for your VM.

Comment: Great answers in the comments Mitch & AlwaysLearning - post 'em as answers so I can upvote them ;)

Comment: Did we find and answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always set a maximum memory limit for SQL Server instances.

A simple rule of thumb is to leave **4GB** or **10%** of total memory free, whichever is larger, and *tweak* as necessary.

If your SQL Server instance is running as a VM, then you also need to set a memory reservation at the host for your VM. Otherwise, the host's 'balloon memory manager' might kick in and steal memory back from your instance.

Ref:

[Server memory configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Understanding Memory Resource Management in VMware](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/perf-vsphere-memory_management.pdf)